# Getting original exception when ProcessStartInfo ErrorDialog = true

Tags: c#, .net, processstartinfo

When using code like this (I don't have permissions to excel.exe and it is by purpose):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("EXCEL.exe");
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.ErrorDialog = true;
Process.Start(psi);
```

I'm getting nice Windows error dialog with appropriate message about lack permissions. That is 100% fine but only when I don't want to log this error.

Suppose I want to log it using code like:

```
try
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("EXCEL.exe");
    psi.UseShellExecute = true;
    psi.ErrorDialog = true;
    Process.Start(psi);
}
catch(Win32Exception ex)
{
    LogError(ex.Message) //FAIL! "The operation was canceled by the user" instead of "Access denied"
}
```

It seems that original exception is lost and no matter if I don't have permissions or excel installed I always get the same exception code (message).

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The exception is lost because you're using `UseShellExecute` and `ErrorDialog`, so they happen in the Windows Shell, not your process and hence not in the .NET Runtime, so there's no exception to catch.  Instead, why don't you set both of these properties to `false` (or at least the `ErrorDialog` property), catch the exception, log it, and then display your own error dialog?

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. My intention is to preserve original Windows messages and using ErrorDialog = false I would have to custom write them :/ for example "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item." (Windows error dialog) != "Access denied" (from error code)

Comment: Even if you don't *want* to, to get the behavior you require you may *have* to.  Surely `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)` isn't that much work?